# Dygraph should show interpolated values in the Legend

Tags: null, interpolation, legend, nan, dygraphs

I have data fields with null or NaN values. Dygraph just hides them in the legend. But i want dygraph to show interpolated values instead.

Can i do that with the valueformatter ? For now i am using hairlines to achieve something similar.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Those are the results of my research after trying to achieve the same thing you asked:

> Can i do that with the valueformatter ?

No, and this is why: `valueFormatter` is called inside `generateLegendHTML` ([link](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/blob/e9155b2c442bf69396d5a456c885f938d38d35da/src/plugins/legend.js#L222) to the source code). And `generateLegendHTML` has `sel_points` (= selected points) as an input. This means that if a point has not been selected (and by "point" we mean "real data that has not been interpolated") it will not pass through `valueFormatter`:

```
for (i = 0; i < sel_points.length; i++) {
  ...
  var fmtFunc = yOptView('valueFormatter');
  var yHTML = fmtFunc.call(g, pt.yval, yOptView, pt.name, g, row, labels.indexOf(pt.name));
```

This is how points are selected before sending them to `generateLegendHTML`: [link](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/blob/e9155b2c442bf69396d5a456c885f938d38d35da/src/dygraph.js#L1783).

I think the only viable solution to achieve the desired result is to overwrite `generateLegendHTML`.

One could also try to overwrite `Dygraph.prototype.setSelection`, but that piece of code looks way more complex.